# ggplot2/grid: keep segments grob arrow same scale regardless of length

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I am adding arrows to my ggplot using grid::segmentsGrob(arrow).  I define the position of the arrow with x-axis coordinates.  For some reason, the height of the arrow scales based on the length of the arrow.  I want the arrows to occupy the same height, and only shorten the length of the arrow.  Am I missing a height parameter?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df <- data.frame(
  Position=(c(1:5000)),
  Signal=(c((rep(c(5),times=2000)), (rep(c(100),times=1000)), (rep(c(5),times=2000))))
  )


Plotv1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col = "#000000"))+
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12)
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-0.3, "npc"),
      y1 = unit(-0.3, "npc"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, length = unit(.15, 'npc')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, fill = "#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 1,
    xmax = 1700
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-0.3, "npc"),
      y1 = unit(-0.3, "npc"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, length = unit(.15, 'npc')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, fill = "#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = 2200
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-0.3, "npc"),
      y1 = unit(-0.3, "npc"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, length = unit(.15, 'npc')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, fill = "#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2500,
    xmax = 5000
  )

ggsave(paste("~/Desktop/Plotv1.png", sep = ""), Plotv1, width = 8, height = 1.7)
```

[image: Plotv1.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you specified the length of the arrow in `"npc"` units aka normalized parent coordinates. As a result the length of your arrows will differ as the absolute width and height of the parent viewport differ, i.e. in your case the viewport for each arrow is the rectangle defined by `xmin` and `xmax`. Instead, use absolute units for the `length` of your arrows. Additionally, I would suggest to use absolute units to position the arrows, too.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df <- data.frame(
  Position = 1:5000,
  Signal = c(
    rep(5, times = 2000),
    rep(100, times = 1000),
    rep(5, times = 2000)
  )
)

segment <- grid::segmentsGrob(
  y0 = unit(-10, "pt"),
  y1 = unit(-10, "pt"),
  arrow = arrow(angle = 45, length = unit(.3, "cm")),
  gp = grid::gpar(lwd = 3, fill = "#000000")
)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = Position, y = Signal, col = "#000000")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size = 12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size = 12)
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  annotation_custom(
    segment, xmin = 1, xmax = 1700
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    segment, xmin = 2000, xmax = 2200
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    segment, xmin = 2500, xmax = 5000
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this indeed was the issue.  I changed the units for arrow length to cm.   Can you elaborate on why you recommend using absolute units for positioning?

Comment: In my experience setting the position in absolute units works better or makes it easier to place the grob as all the non-data ink aka the axis ticks, text and title as well as the plot margin are set in absolute units. Hence, using absolute units you can account for that and place the arrows independent of the plot height (or width). See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77117930/12993861) from me where using absolute units allows to place the annotations straight below the axis text, whereas using relative units would have required a lot of fiddling.