# Improve presentation of logistic regression plot R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend, x-axis

It's my first time asking a question. I hope it is ok.

Minimum reproducible example:[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTlR4.png)

```
library(tidyverse)


OR <- c(0.98, 1.02, 1.00, 1.03)
conf.low <- c(0.64, 0.69, 0.65, 0.68)
conf.high <- c(1.51, 1.56, 1.54, 1.58)
Variable <- c("variable", "variable", "variable", "variable")
cohort <- c("cohort 1", "cohort 2", "cohort 3", "cohort 4")
df <- data.frame(OR, conf.low, conf.high, Variable, cohort)  

ggplot(df, aes(x = OR, xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high, y = Variable, group = cohort, 
color = cohort)) + 
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), linewidth = .25, linetype = "dashed", colour = "red") +
  labs(x = "OR (95% CI)", y = "", color = "") +
  scale_x_log10(limits= c(0.5, 2), breaks = c(0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.33, 2.0)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Add text "Lower in intervention group" and "Lower in control group" below the x-axis to the left and right respectively of the line at 1.0.
2. Reverse the order of the lines so the green line (cohort 1) appears at the top of the plot.
3. Move the position of the legend to the left so that it is within the area of the plot (or even better add the text as annotations above each line)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I tried to search for the answer but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the order of the lines convert the variable mapped on `group` to a `factor` and reverse the order of the levels which could be achieved in one go using `forcats::fct_rev`. To get rid of the legend you could use a `geom_text` or a `geom_label` to add the labels on top of the line. I use `geom_label` as it automatically adds some padding. Most tricky part is to put some annotations below the x axis. To this end I prefer to use an `annotation_custom` over an `annotate` as it gives more control to place the label. Additionally, we have to set `clip="off"` via `coord_cartesian` and finally I shifted the axis title by increasing the top margin via `theme()` options.

```r
library(ggplot2)

OR <- c(0.98, 1.02, 1.00, 1.03)
conf.low <- c(0.64, 0.69, 0.65, 0.68)
conf.high <- c(1.51, 1.56, 1.54, 1.58)
Variable <- c("variable", "variable", "variable", "variable")
cohort <- c("cohort 1", "cohort 2", "cohort 3", "cohort 4")
df <- data.frame(OR, conf.low, conf.high, Variable, cohort)

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = OR, xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high,
  y = Variable,
  color = cohort,
  group = forcats::fct_rev(cohort)
)) +
  geom_pointrange(
    position = position_dodge(width = .5)
  ) +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = cohort,
      x = conf.low
    ),
    hjust = 0,
    fill = NA,
    vjust = 0,
    label.size = 0,
    position = position_dodge(width = .5)
  ) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1),
    linewidth = .25,
    linetype = "dashed", colour = "red"
  ) +
  labs(x = "OR (95% CI)", y = "", color = "") +
  scale_x_log10(
    limits = c(0.5, 2),
    breaks = c(0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.33, 2.0)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::textGrob(
      label = "Lower in intervention group",
      x = unit(.5, "npc"),
      y = unit(0, "npc") - unit(16, "pt"),
      vjust = 1,
      gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 10)
    ),
    xmax = log10(1)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = grid::textGrob(
      label = "Lower in control group",
      x = unit(.5, "npc"),
      y = unit(0, "npc") - unit(16, "pt"),
      vjust = 1,
      gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 10)
    ),
    xmin = log10(1)
  ) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20))
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]